# Load data web page in react

Tags: reactjs

I'm looking for a way to refresh the data in the page, I want the data from my fetch request to replace the `loading` text.
Any idea how to do so?

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

function BitCoin() {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://localhost:3001/bitcoin")
      .then((res) => res.json()) 
      .then((data) => setData(data.message))
      .then(console.log(data));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div style={{textAlign:"center", fontFamily:"Comic Sans MC", fontSize:"100"}}>
      THIS IS THE BitCoin PAGE

      <nav>
        <Link to="/"> Home </Link>
      </nav>

      <nav>
        <Link to="/coins"> Coins </Link>
      </nav>

      <p>{!data ? "Loading..." : data}</p>
    </div>
  )
}

export default BitCoin;
```

Comment: Looks like this is what u are actually doing. Can u be more specific in what u want to achieve exactly? Thanks

Comment: when I'm running my code, server and client, I can't, for some reason, get the data I fetched and I'm stuck with the loading screen (also the log is not showing)
thanks <3

Comment: Looks like it might be some issue connecting to the server from the client. Could u check if the request is being done and resolved properly?

Comment: the server seems to react to the fetch request, when the page runs, the server logs the message I want to send, then sends it of course, is there any way I could check if the client gets the message from the server??

Comment: You can `console.log` the `res` value or use the `devtools` of the browser u are using

Comment: when I'm trying to log the res I'm getting an error (    the res is not defined)